# How to apply styles in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am working with PHPExcel & i want to give same style to some cells.
I have tried below code, but it applies style to only A1.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1','B2','B3','c4')->getAlignment()->setIndent(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply provide a list of cells like `'A1','B2','B3','c4'` because `getStyle()` only accepts a single argument; but that argument can be either a single cell (e.g. `'A1'`) or a range of cells like `'A1:C4'`

so

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1:C4')
    ->getAlignment()->setIndent(1);
```

is perfectly acceptable, and actually recommended because it's a lot more efficient setting styles for a range than for individual cells

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scheduleSheet->getStyle("A1:C3")
    ->applyFromArray('fill' => [
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => ['rgb' => 'ACA5A5']
        ]
    );
```